# how to sip registration in server for an ios app

Tags: ios, swift, sip, voip, sdp

i am creating an app for internet calling using VoIP . But have no idea how to send SIP registration to sever to stabilise connection  between to devices .
and any suggestions for the library

Comment: Your question is too general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linphone library](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone) for that purpose. Although be prepared that documentation is not ideal and you will need to figure some of the things by yourself. You however can inspire by [this tutorial project](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/tutorials/-/blob/master/ios/swift/3-OutgoingCall/OutgoingCall/OutgoingCall.swift)

Comment: @Krishan chand tiwari. Did my answer provide solution to your problem ?

Comment: how could you do this if you didn't want to have a dependency on a 3rd party library? In other words if you wanted to implement yourself the functionality that Linphone provides?